# How to change divs placing from horizontal to vertical using css?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs in my footer, those divs are used for footer and you can see them horizontally on the bottom of the page.

```
<div class="footer-text footer_mainDIV">
    <div class="footer_leftDIV">
        All rights reserved
    </div>
    <div class="footer_middleDIV">
        <a href="url">Help</a>

    </div>
    <div class="footer_rightDIV">
        Version 6.0
    </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.footer_mainDIV {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer_leftDIV {
    text-align: left; 
    position : absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 33%;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer_middleDIV {
    height: 50px;
    width: 33%;
    margin: auto;

}

.footer_rightDIV {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 33%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

What is the way to make my divs from horizontal view to vertical when minimizing the browser using css?
I need the divs to become vertically when the browser is minimized and there is not enough width to see them horizontally.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media query to achieve this. For example i have targeted 480 pixels.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 480px)
{
 .footer_leftDIV, .footer_middleDIV, .footer_rightDIV
 {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    left:0;
  }
}
```

[**SAMPLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/xejeLja9/)

Comment: As i told you need to add alignment related styles. I will update my answer with sample fiddle. Updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can update your given css with it

```
.footer_mainDIV {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:20px;

}

.footer_leftDIV {
    text-align: left; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
}

.footer_middleDIV {
    height: 50px;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;

}

.footer_rightDIV {
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 33%;
}
```

But add it in a relative property div i hope it will work for you.